# Which versions of the Microsoft.NET framework work with Windows Powerhsell?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, powershell

I am working on providers and cmdlets for Powershell 1 & 2.

Which version(s) of the framework should I target for my extensions?

I assume Microsoft.NET 2 will work fine. What about 3.0 and 3.5? Microsoft.NET 4.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **demands** 2.0, but .NET 3.0 and 3.5 still share the CLI version, so if 2.0 works, 3.0 and 3.5 should be fine **if** the machine has them installed; there are *lots* of examples of, for example, WCF (3.0) with powershell. Harder to tell on 4.0 since it isn't RTM.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought. Powershell seemed to behave this way. I just couldn't find any documentation on it. Thanks!

Comment: .NET 4 assemblies won't work in PowerShell 2 by default. But you can force PowerShell to use the .NET 4 CLR. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime for number of examples. I've successfully used the COMPLUS activation method referenced here https://gist.github.com/882528 and prefer it because it only turns on .NET 4 CLR for the specific scripts I want to run.