# How do I find out what .net runtime a dll is built upon programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I find out what .net runtime a dll is built upon programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine framework (CLR) version of assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310701/determine-framework-clr-version-of-assembly)

Answer (score 4):

The [Assembly.GetAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly.aspx) method returns an [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx) that has an  [Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.imageruntimeversion.aspx) property. That property's description says, "Gets a string representing the version of the common language runtime (CLR) saved in the file containing the manifest."

I think that's what you're after.