# find the CLR version of a DLL

Tags: c++, .net, clr, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine framework (CLR) version of assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310701/determine-framework-clr-version-of-assembly)

I need to get the CLR version of a .NET DLL from a C++ process.
I tried using the .NEt method `GetVersionFromProcess` but it only receives a process handle.
If I send it the DLL's file handle or base address, it will return `E_INVALIDARGS`.

Comment: And will you show us your code which doesn't work for you?

Comment: @ben voigt: I need this programatically and from a C++ process. As I wrote.

Comment: IMetaDataImport2::GetVersionString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These native functions return the .NET version used by an assembly:

- Newer: [ICLRMetaHost::GetVersionFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233127.aspx)
- Older: [GetFileVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232525.aspx)