# How to get target runtime info from a .NET assembly in a C# program?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Nowadays, .NET applications can be created, among others, with .NET Core and with the full .NET framework.

Both .NET Core and the full .NET Framework uses assembly files (dll files) to package the application.

Now given an assembly file loaded in a C# program via Reflection, **how to know which environment(.NET Core, Full Framework...) it is targeting?**

#### UPDATE

**This turned out to be a duplicate question**, I wanted to highlight [the most helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623516/1182189) in the [pre-existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310701/determine-framework-clr-version-of-assembly) question:

```
   Assembly assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath("Lib.dll");

   var targetFrwrk = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>().FrameworkName;
```

The `TargetFrameworkAttribute.FrameworkName` property contains the name of the target framework. For example: `.NETStandard,Version=v1.6` or `.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2` .

Comment: Runtimes don't build assemblies, compilers do. Those are under no obligation to record the framework they were using (nor is that generally useful information, nor for that matter does a compiler need to run any managed code at all). The linked question may be an appropriate duplicate if you want to know what framework an assembly is natively targeting. Otherwise, I can't help but wonder why you think you need to know.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Looks like he updated the question to clarify "targeting" was what was meant.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for your clarifications.