# warning: the predefined type 'system.func' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new to wp7. I have a warning, when i build the program, which was done using c# in visual studio 2010 express for windows phone, It shows a warning:

The predefined type 'System.Func' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Users\arul\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\data\data\SQLiteClient\Community.CsharpSqlite.WP.dll'

It shows this warning after add a reference to the Community.CsharpSqlite.WP.dll.

Please help me to clear my errors.
Thank you...

Comment: Hi, I think a same error was found   [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806332/visual-studio-2010-can-no-longer-build-net-v3-5)   maybe read this post help you...

Comment: The above shown solution by you cannot solve the warning. Give a step by step solution to clear the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stumbled on this page when attempting to build [SQLiteClient](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/) for Windows Phone 8. I found by opening the project directly, right-clicking on the solution and selecting "Upgrade to Windows Phone 8" I was able to correct this error.