# How do I run PowerShell scripts in debug mode in PowerGUI under .NET 4 Framework?

Tags: powershell, powergui

I've read [the whole thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/launch-powershell-under-net-4/2096906) about running PowerShell under .NET 4.0, including the warnings about what happens when using the registry keys to make the scripts run under that framework.

So far, I only get the desired result with the registry keys.  Is anyone aware of a way to make this work without changing the registry keys?  When I checked [PowerGUI's discussion boards](http://powergui.org/thread.jspa?threadID=11948), even they pointed to the stackoverflow thread.  Has anyone come up with something better since April 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE "something better" - short of PowerGUI being recompiled to target .NET 4.0 - no.  Out of curiousity, what .NET 4.0 feature are you trying to access in .NET 4?

Comment: Oh, bignum support would be quite nice to have natively. Some Project Euler tasks are awkward to do otherwise.

Comment: We have some custom cmdlets we're using for UI automation that are compiled under .NET 4.

Answer (score 4):

1- Go to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerGUI" and create a "ScriptEditor.exe.config" file.

2- Paste this xml in the file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration> 
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> 
    </startup> 
</configuration>
```

3- Enjoy

This way, your change won't alter the whole machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a dev but maybe you create a config file for powergui. Check this page:

http://poshcode.org/1971

Comment: The config file only applies for PowerShell ISE.  I've already made that configuration file change.