# How to speed up startup of Powershell in the 4.0 environment?

Tags: performance, powershell

I'm considering using Powershell scripts for triggers on our Perforce server. Unfortunately, even on our fast hardware it still takes 2 seconds for Powershell to start up. Now, this doesn't seem like much time unless you consider that 200 users are pounding the server constantly, and a trigger may (depending on conditions) cause a table lock while it runs, stalling out other related requests.

I'm looking for ways to reduce the startup time of Powershell. Things that I've found on Google:

- *Reduce the profile.* This is a default installation, no profile customization, no PSCX, etc. so this doesn't help.
- *Run NGEN on Posh binaries.* This is old advice for a V1 issue. We're on V2.
- *Keep it warm.* Initial Posh startup is slow but later startups are fast. Also not helpful for us. On the server the warm start is 2 seconds and it's kept warm by frequent requests.
- *Don't use Powershell for this purpose.* Well, I'm hoping to avoid that "solution"...

Does anyone have any other suggestions for cutting startup time? I'm not expecting a startup as fast as cmd.exe or a .NET command line app, but if I can get this to .5 seconds I think we'll be ok. Impossible?

**UPDATE** - it turns out this is a 4.0 issue. If I add a config file as described in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime) the startup takes 2 seconds. If I leave it at its default, then startup is under a quarter second.

Then I thought..perhaps it's a 4.0 GAC issue. So I ran the script on the [PowerShell Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/speeding-up-powershell-startup-updating-update-gac-ps1/) but it says all the assemblies are already ngen'd. I made sure that it is indeed using the 4.0 ngen as well.

So I'm left with two options:

- Figure out why 4.0 is so much more expensive than 3.5.
- Switch to the 3.5 framework where I do not need it and I do need the performance.

I'd love to solve the first but don't know where to start. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're probably out of luck if you stick with the console host powershell.exe, unless you feel like writing an optimized script processor by hosting a runspace/runspacefactory in a custom console application - or a windows service - you roll yourself. You might shave a second off, but 0.5s startup for a .NET application is unlikely, especially if the servers are tight for memory.

Comment: Ok I found out it's a 4.0 issue. Updated question.

Comment: Urgh. You're forcing powershell v2.0 to run on v4 framework? It ain't designed to do that. I wish I had more details... do you have dotTrace or ANTS profiler to figure out where the bottlenecks are?

Comment: If you read that SO article closely, you'll see that it's about hosting System.Management.Automation.dll in a managed 4.0 environment. Like the guy says, the console host (powershell.exe) is not optimized for 4.0 - in fact, powershell.exe is not even a managed app - it's native. It hosts the CLR.

Comment: It's not supported? Oh. Well, Powershell 2 runs with v4 for us with no problems that I've seen so far. Just the startup delay issue. And the SO article talks about both a 4.0 app hosting Powershell, as well as Powershell itself using 4.0 assemblies. I could try to analyze it with a .net profiler but I don't think that's going to give me anything I can act on.. Might try it anyway out of curiosity.

Answer (score 26):

> Run NGEN on Posh binaries. This is old advice for a V1 issue. We're on V2.

I've been playing with this under V3, and I found out that some images were
generated.

And it certainly feels like startup is now much faster. I'll know better after a
reboot, as the first time is always the worst. The (my updated) script to do so
with Win 7 is

```sh
$env:path = [Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % {
  if (! $_.location) {continue}
  $Name = Split-Path $_.location -leaf
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "NGENing : $Name"
  ngen install $_.location | % {"`t$_"}
}
```

Comment: I've observed that with a clean install of Windows 8.1, this advice applies and reduces Powershell startup time by about 10x (if an empty profile is present).

Answer (score 2):

Following an excellent answer to [my question on Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c777c2dc-0014-4ec6-b2ba-9711121f63d5/powershell-slow-to-start-on-clean-install-with-empty-profile-present?forum=w8itprogeneral), I discovered a much easier way to trigger NGEN manually (since it seems it doesn't happen automatically on a clean install of Windows 8.1):

```
schtasks /Run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\.NET Framework\.NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319"
schtasks /Run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\.NET Framework\.NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319 64"
```