# What are all of the generic collections/types in the 4.0 .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, .net-4.0

Is there an exhaustive list of all of the "base" (not used in an object-oriented sense but more in a common sense) generic types in the 4.0 .NET Framework? I have found [this list](http://www.canaware.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1112) that I often send newer/mid-level devs to so they can understand how non-generic types map to generic types, but this is by no means exhaustive. I'm looking for something that also includes things such as `KeyValuePair<>`, `Tuple<>`, and other basic generics that may not be very-well known. Interfaces such as `IObservable<>` would be nice but not necessarily required.

Comment: Maybe we could write all the generics we suppose useful as answers below? And you would generate list of types from answers?

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're asking for needs to be better defined. `KeyValuePair<>` and `Tuple<>` aren't collection types (though `KeyValuePair` is closely associated with `Dictionary<>`). `IObservable` is also not a collection interface, though `ObservableCollection<T>` does make use of it. Do you want types like `IQueryable`, which don't represent a collection but a repository (of undefined size) that you can run queries against?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a powershell fragment to list all the generic types in the system assemblies

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | 
    ? { $_.FullName -match "^System" -or $_.FullName -match "mscorlib"} |  
        % { $_.GetTypes() | ? { $_.ContainsGenericParameters } }
```

This could be adapted to give a more comprehensive list. If you load [powershell w/ a .Net 4 config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/launch-powershell-under-net-4), you'll get the 4.0 list.

```
Count Name                      
----- ----                      
    1 System.Xml
   12 System.Data
   67 System
  187 mscorlib
  325 System.Core
```

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio open the object explorer, choose .NET 4 Framework, search for `IEnumerable<T>` and expand the list of derived types. It's way too much to paste here :-).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could reflect on all the BCL assemblies and use the IsGenericType method to get a list of generic types.

Answer (score 2):

You can find this in the System.Collections.Generic namespace
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx

Comment: It is not full, there are other types and interfaces like IQueryable<T> in other namespaces and assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you some answers:

1. **[System.Collections.Generic Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx)**;
2. **[System.Collections.Concurrent Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx)**.

The **System.Collections.Generic** namespace provides most of the generic collections that we already know from .NET 3.5. There was already providing three thread-safe collections:

- [SynchronizedCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx);
- [SynchronizedKeyedCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668294.aspx);
- [SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404554.aspx).

The **System.Collections.Concurrent** namespace namespace provides thread-safe generic collections.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my code. Add more assemblies as you desire.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly[] assemblies = new Assembly[] { 
            typeof(string).Assembly,
            typeof(Uri).Assembly, 
            typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly};

        List<string> final = new List<string>();

        Debug.WriteLine("Checked assemblies: ");
        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(assembly.FullName);

            Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
            IEnumerable<Type> genericTypes = types.Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.IsPublic);
            foreach (Type t in genericTypes)
            {
                final.Add(t.FullName);
            }
        }

        final.Sort();

        Debug.WriteLine("Generic classes: ");
        foreach (string s in final)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Results:

- Checked assemblies:
- mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- Generic classes:
- System.Action`1
- System.Action`10
- System.Action`11
- System.Action`12
- System.Action`13
- System.Action`14
- System.Action`15
- System.Action`16
- System.Action`2
- System.Action`3
- System.Action`4
- System.Action`5
- System.Action`6
- System.Action`7
- System.Action`8
- System.Action`9
- System.ArraySegment`1
- System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`1
- System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1
- System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2
- System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`1
- System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack`1
- System.Collections.Concurrent.IProducerConsumerCollection`1
- System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner`1
- System.Collections.Concurrent.Partitioner`1
- System.Collections.Generic.Comparer`1
- System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2
- System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer`1
- System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1
- System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1
- System.Collections.Generic.IComparer`1
- System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2
- System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
- System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1
- System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1
- System.Collections.Generic.IList`1
- System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1
- System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2
- System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1
- System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode`1
- System.Collections.Generic.List`1
- System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1
- System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2
- System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2
- System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1
- System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1
- System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1
- System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2
- System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1
- System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1
- System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection`1
- System.Comparison`1
- System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1
- System.Converter`2
- System.EventHandler`1
- System.Func`1
- System.Func`10
- System.Func`11
- System.Func`12
- System.Func`13
- System.Func`14
- System.Func`15
- System.Func`16
- System.Func`17
- System.Func`2
- System.Func`3
- System.Func`4
- System.Func`5
- System.Func`6
- System.Func`7
- System.Func`8
- System.Func`9
- System.IComparable`1
- System.IEquatable`1
- System.IObservable`1
- System.IObserver`1
- System.Lazy`1
- System.Linq.EnumerableExecutor`1
- System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1
- System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1
- System.Linq.IGrouping`2
- System.Linq.ILookup`2
- System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1
- System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1
- System.Linq.IQueryable`1
- System.Linq.Lookup`2
- System.Linq.OrderedParallelQuery`1
- System.Linq.ParallelQuery`1
- System.Nullable`1
- System.Predicate`1
- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1
- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable`2
- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder`1
- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuleCache`1
- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StrongBox`1
- System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule`1
- System.Security.AccessControl.AuditRule`1
- System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity`1
- System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1
- System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1
- System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1
- System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1
- System.Tuple`1
- System.Tuple`2
- System.Tuple`3
- System.Tuple`4
- System.Tuple`5
- System.Tuple`6
- System.Tuple`7
- System.Tuple`8