# How can I load an assembly and use it in powershell?

Tags: powershell, .net-assembly, powershell-3.0

I read the suggestions on [How to load assemblies in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923074/how-to-load-assemblies-in-powershell), but I didn't really understand it and I don't know how to apply it to my situation.

I'm trying to load this assembly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx so that I can serialize an object, and being very new to powershell I feel like I'm in over my head.

Can anyone guide me to how I go about loading this assembly into a script?  I'm getting the error:

`make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded`

And when I use `Add-Type -Namespace System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` it prompts me for information for which I don't know how to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BinaryFormatter` is present in `mscorlib.dll` and is already loaded. To create a new object, you can do the following:

```
$formatter = new-object System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
```

Comment: Just a side note: Namespace parameter has different purpose than the one you've guessed. Read `Get-Help Add-Type -Parameter Namespace` to find out more.