# How do you get the value dynamically of a static class' properties?

Tags: powershell

I want to loop over a static class's properties.
`[EnvDTE.Constants] | get-member -static | where-object {$_.MemberType -eq "Property" -and $_.Name -like 'vsP*'}`

Instead of then going and manually typing the names like:
`[EnvDTE.Constants]::vsProjectItemKindMisc`

tried:

- `| Select-Object {$_.Value}`
- `| Select-Object {$([EnvDTE.Constants]::$_.Name)}`
- `| Invoke-Expression "[EnvDTE.Constants]::$_.Name"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go the .NET BCL route:

```
[EnvDTE.Constants].UnderlyingSystemType.GetFields('Static,Public').Where({$_.Name -match 'vsP*'}).Foreach({$_.Name + " = " + $_.GetValue($null)})
```

Or perhaps a bit more PowerShelly:

```
[EnvDTE.Constants].UnderlyingSystemType.GetFields('Static,Public') | 
    Where Name -match vsP* | Foreach {$_.Name + " = " + $_.GetValue($null)}
```

Or:

```
[EnvDTE.Constants] | gm -static -MemberType Property -Name vsP* | 
    Foreach { invoke-expression "'$($_.Name) = ' + [$($_.TypeName)]::$($_.Name)" }
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, filter left (here it probably does not change much, but its good habit):

```
[EnvDTE.Constants] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property -Name vsP*
```

One you have `MemberDefinition` objects:

```
| Foreach-Object { [EnvDTE.Constants]::"$($_.Name)" }
```

Your last attempt would work, if you would use subexpression there (though I recommend against it, `Invoke-Expression` should be used only if really necessary).

Comment: Typo: Look at the time I've used int `Foreach-Object` block - I missed 'v' in type name... Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The first example you gave is correct, but doesn't appear to work for that namespace. Both of these work:

```
[system.math] | Get-Member
[system.net.webrequest] | Get-Member
```

If you have the dll file you can [load it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923074/how-to-load-assemblies-in-powershell).

Comment: the namespace is working the same as `[System.math] | get-member -static | where-object {$_.MemberType -eq "Property"} ` what doesn't seem to work is being able to access the value of what you get back from executing them this way without going back and typing the names out