# Unable to find type [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded

Tags: powershell, compression, runtime-error, powershell-2.0, .net-assembly

I wrote this PowerShell script to archive all log files created during a certain date range.

```
$currentDate = Get-Date;
$currentDate | Get-Member -Membertype Method Add;
$daysBefore = -1;
$archiveTillDate = $currentDate.AddDays($daysBefore);

$sourcePath = 'C:\LOGS';
$destPath='C:\LogArchieve\_'+$archiveTillDate.Day+$archiveTillDate.Month+$archiveTillDate.Year+'.zip';

foreach( $item in (Get-ChildItem $sourcePath | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -le $archiveTillDate }) )
{
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem");
    $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal;
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcePath,$destPath, $compressionLevel, $false);
}
```

It works until the `foreach` loop, but once in the loop it gives these errors:

```
Unable to find type [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:4 char:65
+ $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel] <<<< ::Optimal;
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

As `System.IO.Compression` is part of .NET 4.5, I have it installed on the system, but I still get these errors. I am on Windows Server 2008 R2 and using PowerShell v2.0

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can manually add a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) class to your PowerShell session.

Remove `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem");` from your script and add the following at the very top:

```powershell
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
```

Or on a 32-bit box:

```powershell
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
```

This presumes .NET 4.5 installed OK on your system and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll` actually exists.

Comment: This is for PowerShell v2, but for PowerShell v3 or later [LoadWithPartialName is supposedly deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923074/how-to-load-assemblies-in-powershell/12924252#12924252).

Comment: Try using `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` instead. It is cleaner and does not have a dependency on the reference assemblies which need an installation of Visual Studio.

Comment: @bincob make your comment into an answer. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @RegEdit, thank you - I have posted it as an answer.

Comment: I have this error being underlined in the code in Powershell ISE - I can't even run the script with or without `Add-Type` or `LoadWithPartialName`.

Answer (score 43):

Try using `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` instead. It is cleaner and does not have a dependency on the reference assemblies which need an installation of Visual Studio.

Comment: Great answer. You also do not depend on file paths.

Comment: This answer only works for assemblies in the global assembly cache. Exceptions include anything under `C:/Program Files/WindowsPowerShell/Modules/`, for example `Microsoft.PowerShell.PSReadline`. These must be loaded with `Add-Type -Path`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure to check your $pshome exe.config file.  I had an issue once where Powershell ISE refused to load a .NET assembly, because the config file had .NET 2.0 listed instead of 4.

Comment: Where is this file?

Comment: Ah, got it, it's `Join-Path $PSHOME 'powershell_ise.exe.config'` which results in "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe.config"

Comment: Powershell LSE seems to be limited to .NET 4.0 - I tried changing the config to both 4.5 and 4.8 and when I started Powershell LSE it popped-up with a Yes/No dialog stating that it requires 4.5/4.8 and "Do you want to install this .NET Framework version now?", to which "Yes" redirects to the Microsoft home page.  Also, I had to follow this guide just to get permission to edit that file: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/you-require-permission-from-trustedinstaller.html.