# Powershell error when using loaded assembly

Tags: .net, powershell, zip

I’m having a problem with using zip compression in a Powershell script.  The code snippet in question is:

```
$zipfile = $targetFile
$file   = 'Script.ps1'

$stream = New-Object IO.FileStream($zipfile, [IO.FileMode]::Open)
$mode   = [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update
$zip    = New-Object IO.Compression.ZipArchive($stream, $mode)

($zip.Entries | ? { $file -contains $_.Name }) | % { $_.Delete() }

#   Add a newer Script.ps1 file with the new Comment Based Help template.
$newFile = "$PSScriptRoot\$file"
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zip,$newFile,"Script.ps1","optimal")

#   Clean up.
$zip.Dispose()
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()
```

The code attempts to delete a file from the archive and then add a newer version of the same file.  When I run the script, I receive the following:

> [ERROR] Unable to find type [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode].
>   Make sure that the  [ERROR] assembly that contains this type is
>   loaded. [ERROR] At
>   C:\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\PowerShellIDEInstallers\PowerShel [ERROR]
>   lIDEInstallers\VSInstallCBH.ps1:141 char:2 [ERROR] +     $mode   =
>   [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update [ERROR] +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [ERROR]     +
>   CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:
>   (System.IO.Compression.ZipArch  [ERROR]    iveMode:TypeName) [],
>   RuntimeException [ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
>   [ERROR]

However, if I run it again, it will work correctly.
I found a few posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923074/how-to-load-assemblies-in-powershell) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007742/unable-to-use-system-io-compression-filesystem-dll)) that spoke of similar problems.  I’m currently using:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
```

At the top of the script.  I also found [this post](http://tfl09.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/using-newer-versions-of-net-with.html) which looked promising, but, did not work.  I should also add that the problem occurs in the ISE, Visual Studio, and the command prompt.  The code will work if I run it a second time in any of the environments.

I’m baffled and at a loss.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave’s answer was a partial clue to the resolution.  Changing the `Add-Type` command as he suggested made things better.  However, the code still failed because the change he suggested now caused the command:

```
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zip,$newFile,"Script.ps1","optimal")
```

to fail.

I was able to correct that and fix the problem once I found:

> To use the extension methods, you must reference the
>   System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly in your project.

With Dave’s suggestion, I simply added the following to correct my problem:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
```

The code now works correctly the first time.

Answer (score 3):

You're close.  You need to load one more assembly in this case.  Use:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression
```