# Powershell ISE to run custom dll method

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2015

Hello I have been trying for long to run a method from a dll I created using the powershell ise.  Now I already run my dll from cmd by using 'dotnet foo.dll' but I would like to use the powershell as well.

Here is my code:
Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    { 
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        } 
    }
}
```

Now I have created a new console app with the .net core framework in VS2017 Enterprise.  I only got a dll file after building no executable.  I have researched online and found how to load the dll file with *[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("pathtofile")* btw LoadWithPartialName doesn't work for some reason.

So after loading I try to invoke the Main method with *[ConsoleApp1.Program]::Main()* and i get this error

```
Unable to find type [ConsoleApp1.Program].
At line:1 char:1
+ [ConsoleApp1.Program]::Main
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ConsoleApp1.Program:TypeName)    [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Please help me I can't find any solution to this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is allowed, but I found the answer here to work:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12924252/3485669

Essentially, instead of using Reflection, use Add-Type:

```
Add-Type -Path "<path to your dll>"
```

After that, you should be able to use `[ConsoleApp1.Program]::Main()` as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer this just gives me another error.

Comment: Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more 
information.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCom 
   mand

Comment: @NikolasPitsillos Are you trying to load the source file directly? (ie. `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("Path\to\program.cs")`)

Comment: @NikolasPitsillos - what version of powershell are you using?

Comment: Version - 5.1.14393.953

Comment: And you are sure you are pointing to the path to your compiled DLL in your call to Add-Path? And not your .CS file?

Answer (score 0):

You try to download .Net core assembly to Powershell, but it uses Net Framework.

Use this command:

```
add-type -Path C:\PathToYourDll\DllName.dll -PassThru
```

You will see something like this:

```
"add-type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."
```

After execute this:

```
$Error[0].Exception.LoaderExceptions

"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of i
ts dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

First you need to load all dependencies for .Net Core. You can find it in your Visual Studio project for dll, under Solution Explorer->Dependencies->SDK.

But it can by done very easy, if you make you dll not as .Net Core project, just .Net Framework project. In this case you need just download your dll:

And execute function from dll:

Comment: I will try this as well and get back to you thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

**YOUR DLL IS NOT .NET FRAMEWORK DLL, IT IS .NET CORE DLL**

You must manually resolve all dependencie

Your dll is .Net core. You must firstly load all .Net core dependencies into your powershell session. You can check missed dependencies by

```
add-type -Path C:\PathToYourDll\DllName.dll -PassThru
$Error[0].Exception.LoaderExceptions
```

You must use .net core project? Because for net core dll is something different to load it into powershell session.

Comment: I will try this as well and get back to you thank you for your answer!