# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to load SQL Analysis Server trace file to database using PowerShell.

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended") 
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo")   
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")

$TraceFileReader = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceFile
$TraceFileReader.InitializeAsReader($TraceFile)
```

This gives below exception. 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.SqlTraceException: 
Failed to initialize object as reader. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi, 
Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am run SQL Server 2014 on Windows 2012 R2. How to load the assembly to PowerShell?

Comment: Don't use LoadWithPartialName any longer. Use Add-Type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923074/how-to-load-assemblies-in-powershell

Comment: Changed to Add-Type, still getting the error.