# Powershell and Forms without Administrator Rights

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script using Powershell to fill out a website form.  I am using my work computer which means I don't have Admin rights.  Is it possible to fill out a form on a website using Powershell commands?  For example, tab 4 times, keystroke "R", "A", etc.,  and then tab to the "Submit" button and click it?

Comment: No. Have your administrator install something more practical for you to use such as [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) or some respectable [Python libraries](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/)

Comment: That's what I figured.  Thank you for the info.

Comment: That's not true, PowerShell can call into .NET libraries and often it's enough to put them in the same folder as your script and load them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923074/how-to-load-assemblies-in-powershell That includes Selenium WebDriver and other useful libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Internet Explorer COM Object:

```
$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("https://yourURL")
while($ie.busy){sleep -mil 200}
```

You can then fill out the form with something like this (There are methods for getting by name/id/tagname etc)(this code might not actually work but it should be kinda similar):

```
$ie.Document.GetElementById("ElementID").value = "yourValue"
....
$ie.document.getElementById("buttonID").click()
```

The thing to watch out for is the security zone your target website is in. If you find that the Document property of the `$ie` object is null after calling `.navigate()` then you or your admin need to mark the target site as safe in the IE security settings for it to work without admin privileges.

P.S.: Here is the Documentation for the `InternetExplorer.Application` Object: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)