# New-Object cmdlet error indicates assemblies not loaded

Tags: sql-server, powershell, assemblies, dacpac

I am trying to extract a `dacpac` from a `SQL Server` database via Powershell script. Using this MS  example found here [Extract a DAC using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/extract-a-dac-from-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16)

The code is as follows:

```
Import-Module SqlServer

## Set a SMO Server object to the default instance on the local computer.  
CD SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT  
$srv = get-item .  
  
## Specify the database to extract to a DAC.  
$dbname = "MyDB"  
  
## Specify the DAC metadata.  
$applicationname = "MyApplication"  
$version = "1.0.0.0"  
$description = "This DAC defines the database used by my application."  
  
## Specify the location and name for the extracted DAC package.  
$dacpacPath = "C:\MyDACs\MyApplication.dacpac"  
  
## Extract the DAC.  
$extractionunit = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacExtractionUnit($srv, $dbname, $applicationname, $version)  
$extractionunit.Description = $description  
$extractionunit.Extract($dacpacPath)
```

I added in the call to load the `SqlServer` module, at the beginning of the script, because this issue had been brought to my attention (right or wrong I don't know)

The error message I am getting is:

```
New-Object: C:\xxxxxxx\ .\extractDac.ps1:21:19
Line |
  21 |  … ctionunit = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.dacpac($srv, $dbname, $app …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.dacpac]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
InvalidOperation:
```

I have installed `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects.170.13.0` in `C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages` And checked to see the package is there.

I used the following to check whether the assembly, containing this type, is loaded:

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | Where-Object Location | Sort-Object -Property FullName | Select-Object -Property FullName, Location, GlobalAssemblyCache, IsFullyTrusted | Out-GridView
```

These are what I have:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
```

So the package has been installed but the assemblies are not loaded? This doc [Load the SMO Assemblies in Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/load-the-smo-assemblies-in-windows-powershell?view=sql-server-ver16) suggests to use the code example for loading the SQL Server Management Objects "If your script references a SMO object before the first command that references the provider or cmdlets from the SQL Server snap-ins."

What can I try next?

Comment: Try doing `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac` before your code

Comment: Thanks. But it generates error `Cannot find path` I thought I would need to add `-path` Your suggestion got me searching. This looked helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278390/powershell-add-type-path-locking-file

Comment: You can use the path to the `.dll`, no idea where it is placed though

Comment: Have you tried to do it this way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell?view=sql-server-ver16 ?