# Hosted PowerShell running .NET 4 Snap-In

Tags: powershell, .net-4.0, powershell-2.0

I created a .NET library and I want to create a GUI that calls the library via PowerShell. In order to call cmdlet I had to add [an entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime) to Windows registry, because that library is compiled against .NET 4.

It works fine, but not for a PowerShell host in GUI. What can I do to set up PowerShell host to run a CLR 4 snap-in?

```
var rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
var myAssembly = new AssemblyConfigurationEntry("AssemblyName", "C:\...\Assembly.dll");
rsConfig.Assemblies.Append(myAssembly);
var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
runSpace.Open();

using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
    ps.Runspace = runSpace;
    ps.AddCommand("Get-MyCmdlet");
    ps.AddParameter("Param1");
    ps.AddParameter("Param2");
    foreach (var result in ps.Invoke()) { // CommandNotFoundException
        Debug.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It was a little bit complicated. I wrote [an article](http://dajbych.net/double-layered-application-with-powershell-in-the-middle) about it. Basically appending an assembly is a wrong approach. The easier way is register that assembly.