# Could not load file or assembly in powershell remote session

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-remoting

I get this error when I try to run an assembly from an powershell remote session

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
the file specified.
```

I started the remote session by

```
Enter-PsSession -ComputerName myComputer -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Powershell
-Credential domain\user
```

But when I run it on the same machine as the same user it has no problems.

**Update:**

I want to do something like

```
if (Test-Path $AssemblyPath) {
    $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $AssemblyPath)).OpenRead()
    $assemblyBytes = New-Object byte[] $fileStream.Length
    $fileStream.Read($assemblyBytes, 0, $fileStream.Length) | Out-Null
    $fileStream.Close()
    $assemblyLoaded = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($assemblyBytes) | Out-Null

    $myObject = New-Object namespaceInMyAssembly.ClassInMyAssembly
    $myObject.doMyAction()
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "run an assembly."  Can you post some sample script that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Does the remote machine have .NET 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 installed?

Comment: @JamesQMurphy: I simply call an .exe but I have the same Problem when I manually load the .exe and I create an Object and execute a Method (via New-Object)

Comment: @KeithHill: The machine has ".NET 4 Multi-Targeting Pack" and ".Net Framework 4.5.1" installed.

Comment: The remoting endpoint `Microsoft.PowerShell` is 64-bit.  Is the assembly you're trying to load x86 architecture (32-bit)?  BTW why not just use `Add-Type -Path $AssemblyPath`?  What version of PowerShell are you on - v2?

Comment: @KeithHill: The Powershell is v2.
corflags of the exe gives me PE: PE32 and 32BIT: 0 -> Any CPU

Comment: Does the computer `myComputer` that you're connecting to run 64-bit Windows?  If so, you're connecting to the 64-bit version of PowerShell.  You can see this by running `icm myComputer {[IntPtr]::Size}`.  If that returns 8 then it's a 64-bit process. If it is, then the *assembly* (not PowerShell) you are trying to load better be AnyCPU or x64 architecture.

Comment: The machine runs 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 and [IntPtr]::Size returns 8. The assembly is compiled for AnyCPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:
My Powershell was configured for .Net 4 in powershell.exe.config but not in wsmprovhost.exe.config. So I couldn't load .Net 4 assemblies from my remote session. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088055/how-to-change-powershell-clr-version-when-running-commands-remotely/12090217#12090217).