# Possible to specify PowerShell CLR Version as an argument

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

Is it possible to run powershell passing it the version of the .NET CLR we require?

Systems using Powershell V2 use CLR version 2 by default, and we need version 4.

We could implement a configuration file to:

- C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe.config
- C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShellISE.Exe.config
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe.config
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShellISE.exe.config

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088055/how-to-change-powershell-clr-version-when-running-commands-remotely):

```xml
<configuration> 
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> 
</startup> 
</configuration>
```

But we don't want make changes on customers servers which may potentially break other programs which rely on PowerShell.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5403227/517852) has some interesting answers, in particular [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5403227/517852) about using activation configuration files for one-off invocations using .NET 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the CLR Version in your script and exit with an error if the minimum requirements are not met:

```
if ($PSVersionTable.CLRVersion.Major -lt 4) {
  Write-Error 'CLR Version 4.0 or newer required.'
  exit 1
}
```

Alternatively, if checking for a minimum PowerShell version would also work, you could put a [`#requires` directive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/02/06/requires-your-scripts.aspx) as the first line in your script:

```
#requires -version 4.0
```