# Setting up 1-click Install for custom Powershell provider

Tags: powershell, provider, snap-in, pssnapin

I've created a custom Powershell provider. However, currently there are a few steps people have to do to get it working on a user's computer:

1. configure Powershell to run against .Net 4 (add a config file in c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0)
2. add a custom formatter (to the System32 for c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0).
3. register the snap-in.

The remainder setup steps are completed by a custom powershell script.

I was wondering if anyone could share their experiences on simplifying the process. Ideally I'd like people to run from a single command (ideally a CommandLet that's completes all the above steps.

Has anyone got any Links or Suggestions or Best Practise they could share?

Comment: I've edited to make it a little clearer what you're asking - essentially Best Practise for deploying Powershell extensions AND THEIR FORMATTERS etc.
For my two-penn'th I'd recommend checking the source of existing Powershell scripts, particularly PSCX (community extensions) that will already be easy to install and come with pre-canned formatters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the following snippets that may help.

**VS Command prompt variables**

For the Visual Studio Command you could try Lee Holmes' http://poshcode.org/2176 or the Powershell Communit extensions (PSCVX). Both from https://superuser.com/questions/104868/run-visual-studio-command-line-tools-in-windows-powershell.

After that it's just the formatter and/or registering the snap-in.

**Configure Powershell to use .Net4**

[How can I run PowerShell with the .NET 4 runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime)