# How to iterate over a folder with a large number of files in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that would go through 1.6 million files in a folder and move them to the correct folder based on the file name.

The reason is that NTFS can't handle a large number of files within a single folder without a degrade in performance.

The script call "Get-ChildItem" to get all the items within that folder, and as you might expect, this consumes a lot of memory (about 3.8 GB).

I'm curious if there are any other ways to iterate through all the files in a directory without using up so much memory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $dirWithMillionsOfFiles
#Now, process with $files
```

you WILL face memory issues.

Use PowerShell piping to process the files:

```
Get-ChildItem $dirWithMillionsOfFiles | %{ 
    #process here
}
```

The second way will consume less memory and should ideally not grow beyond a certain point.

Comment: Thanks for the nice and simple solution. I had always thought pipelining in powershell return the entire result before processing next function.

Comment: This actually still requires `O(n)` memory, but if it solves the problem then I agree it's the best solution.

Answer (score 13):

If you need to reduce the memory footprint, you can skip using `Get-ChildItem` and instead use a .NET API directly.  I'm assuming you are on Powershell v2, if so first follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime) to enable .NET 4 to load in Powershell v2.

In .NET 4 there are some nice APIs for *enumerating* files and directories, as opposed to returning them in arrays.

```
[IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles("C:\logs") |%{ <move file $_> }
```

By using this API, instead of `[IO.Directory]::GetFiles()`, only one file name will be processed at a time, so the memory consumption should be relatively small.

**Edit**

I was also assuming you had tried a simple pipelined approach like `Get-ChildItem |ForEach { process }`.  If this is enough, I agree it's the way to go.

But I want to clear up a common misconception: In v2, `Get-ChildItem` (or really, the FileSystem provider) does **not** truly stream.  The implementation uses the APIs `Directory.GetDirectories` and `Directory.GetFiles`, which in your case will generate a 1.6M-element array before any processing can occur.  Once this is done, then yes, the remainder of the pipeline is streaming.  And yes, this initial low-level piece has relatively minimal impact, since it is simply a string array, not an array of rich `FileInfo` objects.  But it is incorrect to claim that `O(1)` memory is used in this pattern.

Powershell v3, in contrast, is built on .NET 4, and thus takes advantage of the streaming APIs I mention above (`Directory.EnumerateDirectories` and `Directory.EnumerateFiles`).  This is a nice change, and helps in scenarios just like yours.

Comment: I think using pipeline with Get-ChildItem like manojlds had suggested would achieve the same thing, but thanks for showing me how to use .Net with powershell! :).

Comment: Yep, get-childitem | foreach-objetc { ... } will also process only one passed item as a time.

Comment: See my edit. `get-childitem | foreach {...}` is only pseudo-streaming, it technically still requires `O(n)` memory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm actually using Powershell V3 on Windows 8, so perhaps that's why it is enumerating through the directory and actually return an FileInfo object for the $input variable. So then, is it true if I were to run this script on Powershell V2 (Windows 7), the $input variable would not be a FileInfo object, but rather an n-size string array?

Comment: No, not quite.  All versions will output `FileInfo` objects.  What I'm saying is that in v2, internally a big string array is generated up front, and elements from that array are used one at a time to build `FileInfo` objects to send down the pipeline.  Only one `FileInfo` is in memory at once, but the array of file paths is stored in its entirety, internally.  In v3, no internal array is created at all, everything is fully streamed.

Comment: Just curious, is it documented somewhere that `Get-ChildItem` uses EmuerateFiles in V3?

Comment: I read it in some email or blog or something, don't recall.  This (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow.aspx) is pretty close to what I read.  But you can see it explicitly by viewing `System.Management.Automation.dll` in Reflector or ildasm.exe.  Look at `Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.FileSystemProvider` method `Dir`.

Comment: @latkin, your way looks awesome, however im new to the powershell and dont know about .net at all. I am facing the same issue asked in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190354/compare-files-using-powershell-and-create-only-non-existing/48190635?noredirect=1#comment83366334_48190635. Since there are millions of million files , is there a way to streamline it using .net. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it without using .Net 4.0. Only Powershell 2.0 and old-fashioned DIR-command:

It's just 2 lines of (easy) code:

```
cd <source_path>
cmd /c "dir /B"| % { move-item $($_) -destination "<dest_folder>" }
```

My Powershell Proces only uses 15MB. No changes on the old Windows 2008 server!

Cheers!