# optimize full path extraction of 1 million files +/- and iteration from file

Tags: powershell, foreach, iteration

I am a programming enthusiast and novice, I am using Powershell to try to solve the following need:

1. I need to extract the full path of files with extension .img. inside a folder with +/- 900 thousand folders and +/- million files. -/+ 900,000 img files.
2. Each img file must be processed in an exe. that is read from a file.
   Which is better to store the result of the GetChildItem in a variable or a file?

I would greatly appreciate your guidance and support to optimize and / or find the best way to speed up processes vs. resource consumption.
Thank you un advance!!
This is the code I am currently using:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'Ascii'
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = “DICOM IMPORT IN PROGRESS”
#region SET WINDOW FIXED WIDTH
$pshost = get-host
$pswindow = $pshost.ui.rawui
$newsize = $pswindow.buffersize
$newsize.height = 3000
$newsize.width = 150
$pswindow.buffersize = $newsize
$newsize = $pswindow.windowsize
$newsize.height = 50
$newsize.width = 150
$pswindow.windowsize = $newsize
#endregion
#
$out = ("$pwd\log_{0:yyyyMMdd_HH.mm.ss}_import.txt" -f (Get-Date))
cls
"`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
"*****************" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
"**IMPORT SCRIPT**" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
"*****************" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
"`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
#
# SET SEARCH FOLDERS #
"Working Folder" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
$path1 = Read-Host "Enter folder location" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
"`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
#
#
# SET & SHOW HOSTNAME
"SERVER NAME" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
$ht = hostname | tee -FilePath $out -Append
Write-Host $ht
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
"`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
#
#
# GET FILES
"`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
#"SEARCHING IMG FILES, PLEASE WAIT..." | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
$files = $path1 | Get-ChildItem -recurse -file -filter *.img | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
# SHOW Get-ChildItem PROCESS ON CONSOLE
Out-host -InputObject $files 
"`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
Write-Output ($files | Measure).Count "IMG FILES FOUND TO PUSH" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
# DUMP Get-ChildIte into a file
$files > $pwd\pf
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

# TIMESTAMP
"`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
"IMPORT START" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
("{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}" -f (Get-Date)) | tee -FilePath $out -Append
"********************************" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
"`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
#
#
#SET TOOL
$ir = $Env:folder_tool
$pt = "utils\tool.exe"
#
#PROCESSING FILES
$n = 1
$pe = foreach ($file in Get-Content $pwd\pf ) {
    $tb = (Get-Date -f HH:mm:ss) | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
    $fp = "$n. $file" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
    #
    $ep = & $ir$pt -c $ht"FIR" -i $file | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
    $as = "`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
    # PRINT CONSOLE IMG FILES PROCESS
    Write-Host $tb
    Write-Host $fp
    Out-host -InputObject $ep
    Write-Host $as
    $n++
}  
#
#TIMESTAMP
"********************************" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
"IMPORT END" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
("{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}" -f (Get-Date)) | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
"`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
```

Comment: With millions of files, I suggest to drop `Get-ChildItem` and avoid the pipeline, which is notoriously slow. Instead, use `[IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles()` function with a `foreach` loop [as shown by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67531923/7571258).

Comment: "*speed up processes vs. resource consumption*" which way? Note that each way would have a different approach. In case you want to save resources: ***do* (correctly) use the mighty [PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines)**

Comment: What is `$pe` doing? In case you want to save memory, you should consider to directly pipe each current item in to the next cmdlet (using @Mathias' answer) rather potting up everything in `$pe` (aka memory)

Comment: @iRon Using `[IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles()` with a `foreach` loop you can have both, speed up and less resource consumption. Speed up due to not using the pipeline and less memory usage as it returns an _enumerator_, which gets the next item only when requested (unless you actively store its output in an array).

Comment: @zett42, good point, I presume that also works for the `ForEach` method: `[IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles(...).ForEach{ $_ }`

Comment: @iRon Unfortunately that doesn't hold true for `.ForEach()`. I just did a test, recursively enumerating all files of a large folder. With `foreach( $path in [IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles(...) ) { $path }`, output starts immediately. However, with `[IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles(...).ForEach{ $_ }`, there is a big delay before output starts. Apparently `.ForEach{}` collects all output into an array first. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247480/discussion-between-iron-and-zett42).

Answer (score 1):

Try using parallel with PoshRSJob.
Replace `Start-Process` in `Process-File` with your code and note that there is no access to console. `Process-File` must return string.
Adjust `$JobCount` and `$inData`.

The main idea is to load all file list into `ConcurrentQueue`, start 20 background jobs and wait them to exit. Each job will take value from queue and pass to `Process-File`, then repeat until queue is empty.

---

NOTE: If you stop script, RS Jobs will continue to run until they finished or powershell closed. Use `Get-RSJob |  Stop-RSJob` and `Get-RSJob |  Remove-RSJob` to stop background work

---

```
Import-Module PoshRSJob

Function Process-File
{
    Param(
       [String]$FilePath
    )
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath 'ping.exe' -ArgumentList '-n 5 127.0.0.1' -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden
    $process.WaitForExit();
    return "Processed $FilePath"
}

$JobCount = [Environment]::ProcessorCount - 2 
$inData = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue[string]]::new(
    [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('S:\SCRIPTS\FileTest', '*.img')
    )
 
$JobScript = [scriptblock]{
    $inQueue = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue[string]]$args[0]
    $outBag = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[string]]$args[1]
    $currentItem = $null
    while($inQueue.TryDequeue([ref] $currentItem) -eq $true)
    {
        try
        {
            # Add result to OutBag
            $result = Process-File -FilePath $currentItem -EA Stop
            $outBag.Add( $result )
        }
        catch
        {
            # Catch error
            Write-Output $_.Exception.ToString()
        }
    }
}
 

 
$resultData = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[string]]::new()
 
$i_cur = $inData.Count
$i_max = $i_cur
 
# Start jobs
$jobs = @(1..$JobCount) | % { Start-RSJob -ScriptBlock $JobScript -ArgumentList @($inData, $resultData) -FunctionsToImport @('Process-File') }
 
# Wait queue to empty
while($i_cur -gt 0)
{
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Doing job' -Status "$($i_cur) left of $($i_max)" -PercentComplete (100 - ($i_cur / $i_max * 100)) 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 # Update frequency
    $i_cur = $inData.Count
}
 
# Wait jobs to complete
$logs = $jobs | % { Wait-RSJob -Job $_ } | % { Receive-RSJob -Job $_  } 
$jobs | % { Remove-RSJob -Job $_ }
$Global:resultData = $resultData
$Global:logs = $logs
```

---

$Global:resultData is array of `Process-File` return strings

Answer (score 0):

> Which is better to store the result of the GetChildItem in a variable or a file?

If you're hoping to keep memory utilization low, the best solution is to *not store them at all* - simply consume the output from `Get-ChildItem` directly:

```
$pe = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -filter *.img |ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.FullName
    $tb = (Get-Date -f HH:mm:ss) | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
    $fp = "$n. $file" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
    #
    $ep = & $ir$pt -c $ht"FIR" -i $file | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
    $as = "`n" | tee -FilePath  $out -Append
    # PRINT CONSOLE IMG FILES PROCESS
    Write-Host $tb
    Write-Host $fp
    Out-host -InputObject $ep
    Write-Host $as
    $n++
}
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` also creates `FileInfo` object for each file and reads file information.
As TS does not need anything except FullName, `[IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles()` is better.

Comment: @filimonic I highly doubt instantiating the `[FileInfo]` objects are going to be the major bottleneck here, but sure - feel free to post another answer below :)

Comment: for SSD listing 1M files is ~ 60 times faster - 0.7s vs 52s using GCI, so IMO, this matters.

Comment: @filimonic does it, though? If the `tool.exe` takes 50ms to execute per file then you're looking at 12 hours 30 minutes and 0.7 seconds instead of 12 hours 30 minutes and 52 seconds :)