# PowerShell 2.0 with .NET 4.0 on Windows 8

Tags: powershell

Windows 8 has PowerShell 3 installed

If I need to get PowerShell 2 I am using

```
PowerShell.exe -Version 2
```

But this runs against .NET CLR 2.0

I want to use .NET CLR 4.0

I tried all approaches from [How can I run PowerShell with the .NET 4 runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime)

But I apply any of them and then

```
PowerShell.exe -Version 2
```

It will actually load PowerShell 3.
To check this type

```
$host.Version
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: May I ask you why you need version 2.0 on .net 4.0 and not using directly version 3 (.net 4 native) ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the 64-bit version of PS doesn't support version 2. On windows 8 64-bit, you need to run the 32-bit version.

This runs the 64-bit version, which doesn't support 2.0 (BAD):

```
%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -version 2.0
```

This runs the 32-bit version (GOOD!):

```
%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -version 2.0
```

Comment: Nope. Did not help. Same effect