# Lazy loading in powershell?

Tags: performance, powershell, lazy-loading

*Can we defer a variable initialization untill it is needed ?*

What I would like to do is **predefine** some variables in my profile that will contain a list of AD computer:

let's say I want:

*$OU1_workstation* to be fill with computers found in OU=workstations,OU=OU1,dc=domain,dc=com

*$OU2_workstation* fill with computers found in
OU=workstations,OU=OU2,dc=domain,dc=com and so on...

I use the following script to do it but it takes 30sec to compute, so currently I can't put that in my profile...

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchScope onelevel -Filter "*" -Properties "name","distinguishedname" |%{
    set-Variable -Name "$($_.name)_workstation" -value (Get-ADComputer -Searchbase "OU=workstations,$($_.Distinguishedname)" -Filter * )
}
```

What options are available in powershell ?

Comment: `$Lazy=[Lazy[PSObject]]::new([Func[PSObject]]{dir})`

Comment: lol I think OP wants to optimize his command to make it faster

Comment: @sodawillow this is not about optimization, I think this is close to what I want : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14503339/381149

Comment: _it takes 30sec to compute, so I can't put it in my profile_ I thought you wanted your script to run faster in order to put it in your profile. I don't think you need more than a (classic) variable to hold the results of your command, like `$myFavouriteComputers`. This variable will then be available each time you use PowerShell.

Comment: @sodawillow we are talking about hundreds of OUs and thousands of computername, no need to query all these objects unless they are effectively use.

Comment: _Can we defer a variable initialization untill it is needed ?_ I missed this, sorry

Comment: have you try using job? `start-job`, `get-job | receive-job`

Comment: @CB. no this is not the point, but I think your response here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482274/how-to-create-a-dynamic-variable-in-powershell-sucha-as-date-time-etc/14503339#14503339 is a good candidate (I didn't have the time to test yet)

Comment: @Kayasax mmhh.. Using job your profile can continue w/o waiting 30 seconds. With a dynamic variable you have to wait each time you call it.

Comment: @CB. mmhh also :) ! using dynamic variable the code will not be run for all  OUs, but likely for just one,  so it should not be too long... I really have to try both suggestions ...

Comment: I'm happy to listen to you.. You and Paris have all my support ..for what it's worth!

Comment: @CB. thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, based on [@Richard's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18866987/381149) of a previous question of mine, I've chosen the following path to achieve some sort of lazy loading : using a `scriptproperty` of a `PSCustomObject`.
So I can put this in my profile

```
#requires -module activedirectory
$server=New-Object PSCustomObject
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchScope onelevel -Filter "*" -Properties "name","distinguishedname" | 
?{
    $_.name -notmatch 'Administrateurs|Administration|Comptes de deploiement|Contacts|Domain Controllers|Groupes|Serveurs|Services' 
} |
%{
    $OU=$_.name
    $s=[scriptblock]::Create("Get-ADComputer -SearchBase ""OU=servers,OU=$OU,DC=domain,DC=com"" -Filter 'name -notlike "" *old""' |select -expand name")
    $server| Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -name $OU -value $s -Force
}
```

then when needed I can call `$server.OU1` to get all server under this OU, `$server.OU2` etc...

Comment: IMHO, it is not really lazy loading. It evaluate `Get-ADComputer ...` command each time you ask for it. It is just different syntax to call function.

Comment: You are right, that's why I said a sort of lazy loading. But this is  good for my daily needs :) and allow to define things without execute it. To avoid executing the code each time I can create another var : `$OU1_server=$server.OU1 ` ...