# Powershell load custom assembly config file

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, app-config, .net-assembly

I have a DLL file, created in visual studio from my c# code. I need to run my code from powershell, therefore I use the Add-Type method to load my assembly.

My Powershell code:
 `Add-Type -Path C:\MyDirectoryWithDllFiles\MyAssembly.dll
[MyAssembly.MyClass]::MyStaticMethod()`

When I put return "Hello World" in MyStaticMethod, everything works fine.

Of course, my program needs some functionality and a config file was required.
I updated my powershell code to this:

```
[appdomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "C:\MyDirectoryWithDllFiles\MyAssembly.dll.config")
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Configuration
Add-Type -Path C:\MyDirectoryWithDllFiles\MyAssembly.dll
[MyAssembly.MyClass]::MyStaticMethod()
```

With the following config file: (MyAssembly.dll.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="myCustomSection" type="MyAssembly.MyCustomConfigurationSetting, MyAssembly" />
    </configSections>

    <!--this is the custom config section for myCustomSection-->
    <myCustomSection>
        <!-- some items -->
    </myCustomSection>
</configuration>
```

In MyStaticMethod I get the items from my config file, and it works fine when I run the code from visual studio. When I run the powershell code, as described above, I get the following error:

> PS C:\MyDirectoryWithDllFiles> [MyAssembly.MyClass]::MyStaticMethod()
>   Errors: [System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error
>   occurred creating the configuration section handler for
>   myCustomSection: **Could not load file or  assembly
>   'MyAssembly'** or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.
>   (C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2EB6.tmp line 4) --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MyAssembly' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the
>   file specified.    at
>   System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(IInternalConfigHost
>   host, String typeString, Boolean throwOnError)

It tries to find 'MyAssembly', as how I have defined it in the the  in the config file. MyAssembly.dll is a dll I have created. But even though I have this line in my powershell it won't work:
Add-Type -Path C:\MyDirectoryWithDllFiles\MyAssembly.dll

Any suggestions how I can get this working?

Comment: I believe that powershell would not load the MyAssembly.dll.config since your assembly is being loaded into the appdomain created by the powershell process. You need to load the config yourself - maybe using ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(MyAssembly.Location);

Comment: It looks like the config file itself is loaded. but then the line
<section name="myCustomSection" type="MyAssembly.MyCustomConfigurationSetting, MyAssembly" />
looks for MyAssembly but cannot load MyAssembly

Comment: Can you try to reorder:


Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Configuration
Add-Type -Path C:\MyDirectoryWithDllFiles\MyAssembly.dll
[appdomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "C:\MyDirectoryWithDllFiles\MyAssembly.dll.config")
[MyAssembly.MyClass]::MyStaticMethod()

Comment: I have reordered it in the order you mentioned. But still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Thanks to JayKul's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23569983/1408786

I added this to the config section, and now it works fine:
*Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null*

```
<section name="myCustomSection" type="MyAssembly.MyCustomConfigurationSetting, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
```