# PowerShell to Get SharePoint Calendar items

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am looking for an option to get SharePoint Calendar items using PowerShell. Could you please answer if you have better way to achieve?

I wants to download all calendar items as csv format from windows 10 machines.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried already? Is this SharePoint Online or SharePoint on-premises? Maybe have a read through these links: https://www.robertkuzma.com/2012/09/get-items-from-sharepoint-list-using-powershell-script/ and https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92451/powershell-function-to-retrieve-all-items-from-a-list

Comment: @LordPupazz I had already checked the two blogs. It is not helping. I am getting snap in not found error. and I am not sure how to install this snapin on workstation machine.

Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with pnp powershell module:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

first connect to site:

```bsh
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "{siteurl}"
```

#### list items

recurring events are stored in one listitem. the recurrence pattern is stored in the field "RecurrenceData". so, if you just wanna get the items as they are stored, you can do that with following command:

```bsh
$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "{listtitle}"
$items = @()
foreach ($item in $listItems) {
    $items += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Title          = $item["Title"]
        Location       = $item["Location"]
        Category       = $item["Category"]
        EventDate      = $item["EventDate"]
        EndDate        = $item["EndDate"]
        fAllDayEvent   = $item["fAllDayEvent"]
        fRecurrence    = $item["fRecurrence"]
        RecurrenceID   = $item["RecurrenceID"]
        RecurrenceData = $item["RecurrenceData"]
    }
}
$items | Export-Csv -Path "items.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

items.csv:

```
"Title";"Location";"Category";"EventDate";"EndDate";"fAllDayEvent";"fRecurrence";"RecurrenceID";"RecurrenceData"
"test";"asdf";"Treffen";"6/12/2020 9:00:00 AM";"6/12/2020 10:00:00 AM";"False";"False";;
"recurring";;;"6/15/2020 9:00:00 AM";"6/24/2020 10:00:00 AM";"False";"True";;"<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>mo</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><daily dayFrequency=""1"" /></repeat><repeatInstances>10</repeatInstances></rule></recurrence>"
"allday event";;;"6/26/2020 12:00:00 AM";"6/26/2020 11:59:00 PM";"True";"False";;
```

#### split recurring events

if you wanna get the recurring events split up, it gets complicated. i tried that with the sprestmethod `"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('{listtitle}')/RenderListDataAsStream"`. in the viewxml you can define the daterange for week, month, or year:

```bsh
$view = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$PSScriptRoot\view.year.xml")
$p = @{
  parameters = @{
    ViewXml = $view
  }
}
$result = Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod -Url "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('{listtitle}')/RenderListDataAsStream" -Method Post -Content $p
$items = $result.Row
$items | Export-Csv -Path "items-year.csv"
```

```xml
<View Type="CALENDAR" TabularView="FALSE" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" Level="1" BaseViewID="2" ContentTypeID="0x">
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <DateRangesOverlap>
        <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
        <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
        <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />
        <Value Type="DateTime">
          <Year />
        </Value>
      </DateRangesOverlap>
    </Where>
  </Query>
  <QueryOptions>
    <RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>
    <ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>
    <CalendarDate>2020-01-01T12:00:00Z</CalendarDate>
  </QueryOptions>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="fRecurrence" />
    <FieldRef Name="EventType" />
    <FieldRef Name="WorkspaceLink" />
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    <FieldRef Name="Location" />
    <FieldRef Name="Description" />
    <FieldRef Name="Workspace" />
    <FieldRef Name="MasterSeriesItemID" />
    <FieldRef Name="fAllDayEvent" />
  </ViewFields>
  <ViewData>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarMonthTitle" />
    <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarWeekTitle" />
    <FieldRef Name="Location" Type="CalendarWeekLocation" />
    <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarDayTitle" />
    <FieldRef Name="Location" Type="CalendarDayLocation" />
  </ViewData>
  <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
</View>
```

in `<CalendarDate>2020-01-01T12:00:00Z</CalendarDate>` you can define the date of the view

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. 
I am Unable to load the powershell module.

Here is list what I have done.
1. Downloaded SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline from https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline/3.21.2005.2
2. Imported Module in PowerShell
3. Command Connect-PnPOnline is not available in the Module. I have tried through below command Connect-SPOService, however it is unsuccessful. Error as Below:

Connect-SPOService : Could not load file or assembly  'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.ResourceManager, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken

Comment: hi, so you downloaded the nupkg, unzipped it in your folder and imported `Import-Module -Global -Force -Name "$PSScriptRoot\sharepointpnppowershellonline\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.psd1"`?
Have you set Execution-Policy and unblocked the downloaded files? [powershell dll error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18805066/8278838)

Answer (score 0):

You could get all fields use the following code:

```
$username = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "password."
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
$SiteURL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"
$ListName = "cal2"
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\ListData.csv"
$ListDataCollection= @()

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $cred
$Counter = 0
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 2000

#Get all items from list
$ListItems | ForEach-Object {
        $ListItem  = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $_ -Property FieldValuesAsText
        $ListRow = New-Object PSObject
        $Counter++
        Get-PnPField -List $ListName | ForEach-Object {
            $ListRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name $_.InternalName -Value $ListItem[$_.InternalName]
            }
        Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($Counter / $($ListItems.Count)  * 100) -Activity "Exporting List Items..." -Status  "Exporting Item $Counter of $($ListItems.Count)"
        $ListDataCollection += $ListRow
}
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$ListDataCollection | Export-CSV $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to custom columns outputed,

```
$username = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "password."
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
$SiteURL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"
$ListName = "cal2"
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\ListData.csv"
$ListDataCollection= @()

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $cred
$Counter = 0
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 2000

foreach($item in $ListItems)
{
$ListDataCollection += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Title          = $Item["Title"]            
                Location = $Item["Location"]
                EventDate =  $Item["EventDate"]
                EndDate=  $Item["EndDate"]#you can add column you want to output
            }

}
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$ListDataCollection | Export-CSV $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
```

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/export-list-items-to-csv-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html

Comment: Hi, I can't install sharepoint online on users machine. Is there any alternative way to go through only binary files without installing the application?

Comment: You could use powershell access SPO directly,just to get the listitems.You could get samples here:https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/09/sharepoint-online-get-list-items-using-powershell.html

Comment: I followed the procedure. I am getting error at below line.

`#Get the List
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
`
Error:

format-default : The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], CollectionNotInitializedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand

Comment: I tried the "split recurring events" approach but it seems like SharePoint ignores the CalendarDate from the xml. No matter what date in the past I try to load, I only get items relative to the current date.