# Convert HTML to PDF using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am new to Powershell.
I have one htlm file and I want to convert that into pdf file using powershell script.

having this error.

```
Unable to find type [iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter].
At C:\Users\Z004APNA\Desktop\Htms_to_Pdf\Generate-HTML_to_PDF.ps1:32 char:1
+ [iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter]::ConvertToPdf($source, $dest)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

I am using this code.

```
$InputLocation = "C:\Users\Z004APNA\Desktop\Htms_to_Pdf"

$htmls = get-childitem  -filter *.htm? -path $InputLocation

#$htmls = Get-ChildItem -Path $InputLocation -Include *.html -Recurse
foreach($html in $htmls)
{
    $filename = $html.FullName
    $basepath = "$($_.DirectoryName)"
    $pdf = $html.FullName.split('.')[0] + '.pdf'
}

Add-Type -Path ($InputLocation+"\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll")
Add-Type -Path ($InputLocation+"\Common.Logging.Core.dll")
Add-Type -Path ($InputLocation+"\Common.Logging.dll")
Add-Type -Path ($InputLocation+"\itext.io.dll")
Add-Type -Path ($InputLocation+"\itext.kernel.dll")
Add-Type -Path ($InputLocation+"\itext.forms.dll")
Add-Type -Path ($InputLocation+"\itext.layout.dll")
Add-Type -Path ($InputLocation+"\itext.styledxmlparser.dll")
Add-Type -Path ($InputLocation+"\itext.svg.dll")
Add-Type -Path ($InputLocation+"\itext.html2pdf.dll")

$source = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($filename)
$dest = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($pdf)
[iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter]::ConvertToPdf($source, $dest)
```

Comment: Searching around, iText is a Java/C# library you bought/dowloaded right? You probably need to look into how to use [C#/.NET assemblies in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079346/how-to-reference-net-assemblies-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Posting [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347872/convert-html-to-pdf-using-powershell#comment120794049_68347872) as answer:

> Searching around, iText is a Java/C# library you bought/dowloaded right? You probably need to look into how to use [C#/.NET assemblies in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079346/how-to-reference-net-assemblies-using-powershell)

With the two top answers being use:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("c:\temp\tempLib.dll")
```

or use the built in Cmdlet Add-Type:

```
Add-Type -Path foo.dll
```

Comment: Can you please share the link where I can get the dll libraries

Comment: uhhhh, how did you know to use `iText` anyway? i mean, it's wherever you downloaded/install the library

Comment: Now I am able get the libraries.
While executing, I am getting this exception

Comment: Exception calling "ConvertToPdf" with "2" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'iText.IO.Util.EncodingUtil' threw an exception."
At C:\Users\Z004APNA\Desktop\Htms_to_Pdf\Generate-HTML_to_PDF.ps1:51 char:1
+ [iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter]::ConvertToPdf("C:\Users\Z004APNA\Deskt ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeInitializationException

Comment: This looks promising [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801440/powershell-load-dll-got-error-add-type-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webdr). I suggest googling specific parts of the error message to figure out if anyone else got a similar problem. My search terms were `"The type initializer for 'iText.IO.Util.EncodingUtil' threw an exception.` or `~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeInitializationException`