# Why won't my .NET 4.0 assembly register to GAC using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, .net-4.0, ssis, gac

I'm using a .ps1 script to register a set of .NET 4.0 assemblies to the GAC on a production Win 2008 server r2. The assemblies have strong names and the **script returns no errors**:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.EnterpriseServices");
[System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish] $publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish;

$publish.GacInstall("D:\MyComponents\EZTrac.Domain.Dealer.dll")
```

After I run this I look in GAC_MSIL (where it should be), and then GAC_32 and GAC_64 for good measure, but it is not in any of these.

I used [this post](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2012/04/installing-custom-ssis-components-gac-powershell/) as a guide. Any idea what I'm forgetting here?

Comment: Any chance the account executing the script doesn't have sufficient permissions to perform the operation?

Comment: Have you verified that "D:\MyComponents\EZTrac.Domain.Dealer.dll" truly exists? Verify it. (Do it, do it!)

Comment: @TheOptimusPrimus, I just verified 100% that the path and component are right where it says they should be

Comment: @billinkc - wouldn't I get some error or feedback somewhere? The Machine admins assure me they have given me the highest level of rights on that box.

Comment: @billinkc - Any particular rights I should check that you know of?

Comment: I need to run, hopefully someone else will have ideas. I was just going with the first thing that popped into my head. Suppose I should ask, .NET 4 is installed on the box, yeah?

Comment: .NET 4 is installed - check!

Comment: Are you running PowerShell as administrator?

Comment: Are you looking for the assembly under C:\Windows\assembly or C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly?  The latter is the correction location for .NET 4.0.  Have you tried using gacutil (.NET 4.0) to install the assembly into the GAC?

Comment: Is your assembly strongly signed?

Comment: After some research it looks like the Win 2008 server was running v2 of powershell  which will not register .net 4 components. We are installing WMF 4 now to get the latest version of powershell. I will repost the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing this out, my comments under the original question are correct. The problem was that v2 of PowerShell cannot register .NET 4.0 components. In order to do that you have to install either [WMF 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) or [WMF 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855) so that you get Powershell 3 or 4.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a small util function I wrote for gaccing assemblies. It does a few check before doing so:

```
function Gac-Util
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $assembly
    )

    try
    {
        $Error.Clear()

        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.EnterpriseServices") | Out-Null
        [System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish] $publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish

        if (!(Test-Path $assembly -type Leaf) ) 
            { throw "The assembly $assembly does not exist" }

        if ([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($assembly).GetName().GetPublicKey().Length -eq 0 ) 
            { throw "The assembly $assembly must be strongly signed" }

        $publish.GacInstall($assembly)

        Write-Host "`t`t$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): Assembly $assembly gacced"
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Host "`t`t$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you [noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965885/why-wont-my-net-4-0-assembly-register-to-gac-using-powershell#comment29789567_19965885): Using System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish in .Net 2.0 does not allow you to register .Net 4.0 assemblies and it returns no errors if anything went wrong. Updating to PowerShell v3 or higher or [running older PowerShell versions using .Net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime) is a solution. Read more about it [here](https://powershellgac.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Alternatives&referringTitle=Documentation).

Other alternatives are using .Net 4.0 gacutil or have a look at my [PowerShell GAC module](https://powershellgac.codeplex.com/) which is able to install .Net 4.0 assemblies in PowerShell v2 and does give errors if anything went wrong.