# Force PowerShell to use .NET CLR Version 2

Tags: .net, sharepoint, powershell, clr

I am running PowerShell 2 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Server (German).

I want to use the SharePoint 2010 Management Console but am getting the following Errors:

```
The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.
```

and

```
Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.1 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime.
```

when calling get-spfarm.

I get the following when I try to identify the Version:

[image: PowerShell Version]

It uses the CLR Version 4.0.30319.1:

This seems to not be supported by SharePoint.

I than tried to run PowerShell as follows:

PowerShell.exe -Version 2.0

But somehow PoweShell still uses the CLR version 4.0.30319.1:

[image: PowerShell Version]

A lot of people on the internet have stated that they had this problem when the windows update KB2506143 was installed. This is **not** installed on my machine.

How can I force PowerShell to use the 2.0 Version of the .NET CRL?

Comment: The problem is still not resolved.
Does anyone have ideas what else I could check to get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have now found a solution to the problem:
We uninstalled the .NET Framework 4 (since we did not need this on the SharePoint Server).
After this we could use the PowerShell for SharePoint again.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the file on Server 2008 is Powershell.exe.activation_config. It's located at C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\NetApp.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check out your `powershell.exe.config` file. Do you see the `/configuration/startup/requiredRuntime` XML element?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5dzwzc9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I do not have a powershell.exe.config file.

I have looked into the following two folders:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

Comment: Maybe you could create a fresh one, and just add the `requiredRuntime` element to it. I think the correct runtime version would be `v2.0.50727`. Look under the c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 folder to be sure.

Comment: I have added the a powershell.exe.config to the following two folders: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" and "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0".    
    
The file looks like this:    
    
`<configuration>    
   <startup>    
      <requiredRuntime  version="v2.0.50727" safemode="true" />    
   </startup>    
</configuration>`    

When I click on powershell.exe nothing has changed.    
Do I have to do something, so that the config file will be read?

Comment: I believe it should be read when you start the application. Try adding the `supportedRuntime` element as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have now added the `supportedruntime`. The file now looks like this:

`<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
      <requiredRuntime  version="v2.0.50727" safemode="true" />
   </startup>
</configuration>`

There is still no change.

Comment: Can you try restarting your computer after the change? That seems odd, that it wouldn't work.

Comment: I have now restarted the SharePoint Server. It still ignores everything. When I call $psversiontable it still mentions that version 4 of the CLR is used, although I have configured in the config file that it should only use version 2.

Answer (score 0):

Either undo any changes you made to your system that forced PowerShell or other .Net applications to use CLR 4. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime).

Or install .Net 3.5 (or 3.0 or 2.0), which will install CLR 2. If you run Windows 8 or 2012 you need do that by changing the Windows features. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).