# Getting result of .Net object asynchronous method in powershell

Tags: powershell, async-await

I'm trying to call an async method on a .Net object instantiated in Powershell :

```
Add-Type -Path 'my.dll'

$myobj = new-object mynamespace.MyObj()

$res = $myobj.MyAsyncMethod("arg").Result

Write-Host "Result : " $res
```

When executing the script, the shell doesn't seem to wait for `MyAsyncMethod().Result` and displays nothing, although inspecting the return value indicates it is the correct type (`Task<T>`). Various other attempts, such as intermediary variables, `Wait()`, etc. gave no results.

Most of the stuff I found on the web is about asynchronously calling a Powershell script from C#. I want the reverse, but nobody seems to be interested in doing that. Is that even possible and if not, why ?

Comment: That's weird. What happens if you call `myobj.MyAsyncMethod` in a similar way but from a C# console app?

Comment: Works on my machine. Are you sure you create your instance successfully? Because the parenthesis are not needed.

Comment: Whenever you use Add-Type, make sure the script runs in a completely new AppDomain/Powershell process. Loaded assemblies can't be unloaded.

Comment: @Noseratio same code in C# from a console app works.

Comment: @I3arnon I think so, otherwise I would have an exception right ? I simplified the code a bit, but the MyObj constructor actually takes parameters so I guess parentheses are OK ?

Comment: @Eris Do you mean that if I change the dll and call Add-Type again, the new one won't be loaded ? (Anyway, the dll didn't change and I respawned a powershell console multiple times with the same problem so I guess it isn't that)

Comment: @guillaume31 when I use parenthesis I get an error. I suggest you try without them.

Comment: @I3arnon you mean when you new up the object or when you call the async method (or both) ?

Comment: @guillaume31 when creating a new instance with `new-object`. When calling a method you need parenthesis.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is a very old thread, but it might be that you were actually getting an error from the async method but it was being swallowed because you were using `.Result`.

Try using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `.Result` and that will cause any exceptions to be bubbled up.

Answer (score 5):

For long running methods, use the `PSRunspacedDelegate` module, which will enable you to run the task asynchronously:

```
$task = $myobj.MyAsyncMethod("arg");
$continuation = New-RunspacedDelegate ( [Action[System.Threading.Tasks.Task[object]]] { 
    param($t)

    # do something with $t.Result here
} );

$task.ContinueWith($continuation);
```

See [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/tahir-hassan/PSRunspacedDelegate).  (Disclaimer: I wrote it).

Comment: I've been looking for a way to use ContinueWith so it doesn't throw an execution context error!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Net.Http'

$myobj = new-object System.Net.Http.HttpClient

$res = $myobj.GetStringAsync("https://google.com").Result

Write-Host "Result : " $res
```

Perhaps check that PowerShell is configured to use .NET 4:

[How can I run PowerShell with the .NET 4 runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime)