# Log Console output of a C# Async Task when called from Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, logging

I am calling a C# DLL from my Powershell script with the following lines of code.

```
Add-Type -Path "PATH_TO_DLL";
$MyClass = New-Object -TypeName MyClass;
$MyClass.MyMethod();
```

The `MyMethod()` method has the following signature:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
```

The `MyMethod()` code outputs stuff by using `System.Console.WriteLine()`. When I execute the powershell code via the powershell command line, I can see this output on the command line. However, if I want to output this to a separate log file by using `Start-Transcript ...` and `Stop-Transcript`, I only get a `VoidTaskResult` that looks as can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/xK76W0h2

I already tried the solutions described in the following threads, but they did not yield the desired result for me. None of the log output that is written by the C# application with `System.Console.WriteLine()` is shown or logged. Why?

[How to capture process output asynchronously in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370814/how-to-capture-process-output-asynchronously-in-powershell)

[Getting result of .Net object asynchronous method in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851704/getting-result-of-net-object-asynchronous-method-in-powershell)

Comment: "[...] but they did not yield the desired result for me. Why?" - well, what kind of result _did_ they yield? What _actually happened_ when you launched the script as a child process?

Comment: I amended the OP.