# How to unzip a Zip File with Powershell Version 2.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

This works for me with PowerShell version 4.0 or higher. But at PowerShell version 2.0 the `Add-Type` isn't possible (type doesn't exist).

```
function unzip {
    Add-Type -Assembly “system.io.compression.filesystem”

    [io.compression.zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory("SOURCEPATH\ZIPNAME", "DESTINATIONPATH")
}
```

Comment: I reply this question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030884/creating-zip-files-using-powershell/44031912#44031912

Answer (score 13):

```
function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
{
   $shell = new-object -com shell.application
   $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
   foreach($item in $zip.items())
   {
      $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
   }
}
```

This leverages Windows's built in zip file support, via the Shell.Application object.  To use this, run the following.

```
>Expand-ZipFile .\Myzip.zip -destination c:\temp\files
```

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-extract-zip-files-using-powershell/

Answer (score 9):

The PowerShell version is just a symptom. It's not the actual cause of the issue. The relevant classes for handling zip archives were added to the `System.IO.Compression` namespace with [.NET Framework 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.compression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (a prerequisite for PowerShell v4) and are not available in [earlier versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.compression%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Install version 4.5 of the .NET Framework and you'll be able to use the `IO.Compression.ZipFile` class in PowerShell v2 as well.

However, in PowerShell v2

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.Filesystem"
```

will throw an error that it cannot find the assembly even if you installed .NET Framework 4.5, so you'll need to replace the line with

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.Filesystem")
```

and change the .Net Framework configuration to [always use the latest CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2096906/1630171) (otherwise PowerShell v2 would use .Net Framework 2.0 instead of 4.5):

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework /v OnlyUseLatestCLR /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

---

An alternative that works out of the box even without .NET Framework 4.5 is the `Shell.Application` COM object, as suggested by [@FoxDeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37814462/1630171). Beware, though, that the `CopyHere()` method runs asynchronously, i.e. it returns immediately without waiting for the actual copy operation to complete. If you want to run it from a script you need to add some sort of delay, because the `Shell.Application` object is automatically destroyed when the script terminates, thus aborting unfinished copy operations.

Comment: Then there is the following error message:
PS C:\Users\test> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.Filesystem")

PS C:\Users\test> [io.compression.zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory("C:\WIN_AGENT.zip", "C:\test\")
Unable to find type [io.compression.zipfile]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:25
+ [io.compression.zipfile] <<<< ::ExtractToDirectory("C:\WIN_AGENT.zip", "C:\test\")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (io.compression.zipfile:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to change the actual .NET Framework Version.
The used .NET Framework Version is 2.0.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. First, Add-Type *is* available in PowerShell V2. Second, [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.Filesystem") will not work with PowerShell V2, since it uses .NET 2.

Comment: @richb You're right in so far that `Add-Type` is available in PowerShell v2. However, if you run `Add-Type -Assembly 'System.IO.Compression.Filesystem'` you'll see that it complains about being unable to find the assembly. Also, it's incorrect that `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName()` wouldn't work in PowerShell v2. You just need to make it [use the latest CLR version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2096906/1630171).

Comment: Interesting Ansgar I did not know about that. For my use case it's not useful. I wanted a script that runs on vanilla Windows 7. If I'm going to change the registry on each computer to make it work I might as well just install PowerShell 5. I also note comments in that answer about negative side effects of forcing PS 2 to run on .NET 4. Nethertheless it's an interesting hack & thanks for the info.

Comment: If you want a script that'll run on a vanilla Windows 7 you're probably stuck with using the `Shell.Application` COM object, b/c AFAICS everything else requires some kind of modification to the system (.NET Framework upgrade, 3rd party programs like 7-zip, etc.).