# Creating Zip files using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I have these below files at a location C:\Desktop\Mobile.

```
    Apple_iphone6.dat
    Apple_iphone7.dat
    Samsung_edge7.dat
    Samsung_galaxy.dat
    Sony_experia.dat
    Sony_M2.dat
```

I need to create a script that writes the similar files into a single zip. So files Apple_iphone6.dat and Apple_iphone7.dat must be into single zip.
So the final zip files created would be:

```
Apple_Files_Timestamp.zip
Samsung_Files_Timestamp.zip
Sony_Files_Timestamp.zip
```

I tried this

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Desktop\Mobile -Recurse -File -Include *.dat | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $date } | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\Desktop\Mobile
```

But it gives me error 'Compress-Archive' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

How can I get this code work?

Comment: [Compress-Archive](https://ss64.com/ps/compress-archive.html) requires PowerShell Version 5+

Comment: I'd first group by the make name `gci *.dat|group {($_.Name).split('_')[0]}` and then iterate the groups to zip with a 3rd party tool like 7zip.

Comment: I just realized i am using lower version of Power Shell. also my code will zip everything in one single zip. But i need to group it. Some code samples will really help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems, I will try to summarize both of them.

**1. Compress files**

In order to use Compress-Archive command you need to have PowerShell 5 as already commented by @LotPings. You can:

- run your script on Windows 10 machine, or Server 2016 which are coming with v5
- download and install PoSh 5, see details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/install-configure)

If you cannot do either of those, you can

- install some module from PowerShell gallery that provides similar functionality via 7-zip tool. Search resultes are [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/items?q=7zip). Download and check those modules before use!
- use .NET 4.5 class, check [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell) here on Stack Overflow

**2. Group files**

Once you group files, you can easily pipe them to compressing command, similar as you already tried. Proper grouping would be achieved with something like this:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Desktop\Mobile'
$Groups = $Files | ForEach-Object {($_.Name).split('_')[0]} | Select-Object -Unique

foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $Files | where Name -Match "^$Group" | Compress-Archive "C:\Desktop\Mobile\$Group.7z"
}
```

Comment: $destination= 'C:\Temp'
$Files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Desktop\Mobile.,*.dat'
$Groups = $Files | ForEach-Object {($_.Name).split('_')[0]} | Select-Object -Unique

foreach ($Group in $Groups) 
{
    $Files | where Name -Match "^$Group" |
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Files,$destination)
}

This isn't creating any zip files. What is missing here?

Comment: specify -DestinationPath with xxx.zip like this: `| Compress-Archive -DestinationPath xxx.zip` will suppress the 7z not supported error and the prompt to ask for destination path

Answer (score 2):

Pre Powershell v5 you can use this. No additional downloads needed.

```
$FullName = "Path\FileName"
$Name = CompressedFileName
$ZipFile = "Path\ZipFileName"
$Zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($ZipFile,'Update')
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($Zip,$FullName,$Name,"optimal")
$Zip.Dispose()
```

Comment: v5.1.16299.251 complains TypeNotFound

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  251
```

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell 2.0 you can't use Compress-Archive, you need download the original terminal executables to zip and unzip files from [here](http://stahlworks.com/dev/?tool=zipunzip).

You can use:

```
zip <path> <zip_name> -i <pattern_files>
```

In your example:

```
zip "C:\Desktop\Mobile" Apple_Files_Timestamp.zip -i Apple*.dat
zip "C:\Desktop\Mobile" Samsung_Files_Timestamp.zip -i Samsung*.dat
zip "C:\Desktop\Mobile" Sony_Files_Timestamp.zip -i Sony*.dat
```

If you need use adittional zip options, visit [zip manual](http://linux.math.tifr.res.in/manuals/man/zip.html).

Comment: The real question then becomes, why are you still using v2? Update it.

Answer (score 0):

- The following script does the grouping,
- the zipping command depends on your chosen zipper.

---

```
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddhhmmss"
Get-ChildItem *.dat|
  Group-Object {($_.Name).split('_')[0]}|
    ForEach-Object {
      $Make = $_.Name
      Foreach($File in $_.Group){
        "{0,20} --> {1}_Files_{2}.zip" -f $File.Name,$Make,$TimeStamp
      }
}
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SO_44030884.ps1
   Samsung_edge7.dat --> Samsung_Files_20170517081753.zip
  Samsung_galaxy.dat --> Samsung_Files_20170517081753.zip
   Apple_iphone6.dat --> Apple_Files_20170517081753.zip
   Apple_iphone7.dat --> Apple_Files_20170517081753.zip
         Sony_M2.dat --> Sony_Files_20170517081753.zip
    Sony_experia.dat --> Sony_Files_20170517081753.zip
```

This link might help [Module to Synchronously Zip and Unzip using PowerShell 2.0](http://blog.danskingdom.com/module-to-synchronously-zip-and-unzip-using-powershell-2-0/)