# unzip zip files into multiple folders with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 5 zip files and 5 folders respectively.
Files are: FranceData.zip, USAdata.zip, GermanData.zip, Italydata.zip and DanemarkData.zip. Folders are: FranceFolder, USAFolder, GermanFolder, ItalyFolder and DanemarkFolder. I would like to know how would I unzip these files into their respective folders using Array in Powershell. I am knew to Powershell and need help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the `Expand-Archive` cmdlet, which is available in PowerShell 5 and above. (PowerShell's version can be checked via the `$PSVersionTable` variable.)

To extract a zip file to a specific folder the following syntax is used:

```
Expand-Archive -Path 'ZipFile.zip' -DestinationPath 'ZipFolder'
```

or

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'ZipFile.zip' -DestinationPath 'ZipFolder'
```

If the `-Path` parameter is used, PowerShell will recognise characters such as `*`, `?`, `[`, `]`, as wildcards, which can cause unexpected behaviour for file-paths that contain square-brackets.
If the `-LiteralPath` parameter is used, PowerShell will not treat any characters as wildcard characters.

---

Assuming all your zip files and folders follow the same naming pattern you could use an array like so:

```
$Countries = @(
    'France',
    'USA',
    'German'
    'Italy',
    'Danemark'
)

foreach ($Country in $Countries)
{
    $ZipFilePath = $Country + 'Data.zip'
    $DestinationPath = $Country + 'Folder'

    Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $ZipFilePath -DestinationPath $DestinationPath
}
```

---

If your files and folders don't follow the same naming pattern you could use a dictionary (or a collection of `KeyValuePair`s), like so:

```
$ZipFilesAndFolders = @{
    'FranceData.zip' = 'FranceFolder'
    'USAData.zip' = 'USAFolder'
    'GermanData.zip' = 'GermanFolder'
    'ItalyData.zip' = 'ItalyFolder'
    'DanemarkData.zip' = 'DanemarkFolder'
}

foreach ($KeyAndValue in $ZipFilesAndFolders.GetEnumerator())
{
    $ZipFilePath = $KeyAndValue.Key
    $DestinationPath = $KeyAndValue.Value

    Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $ZipFilePath -DestinationPath $DestinationPath
}
```

---

**With PowerShell 4 (and 3)**

If you have .Net Framework 4.5 installed, you can use `Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive` which was created by the PowerShell team.
PowerShell 4 requires .Net Framework 4.5 so this should work without any system changes needed.
The module can be found at https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive

The syntax used is identical, the function is `Expand-Archive` and the parameters are `-Path`, `-LiteralPath`, and `-DestinationPath`.
Just ensure that you have imported the module before using it, this can be done using the `Import-Module` cmdlet like so:

```
Import-Module -Name 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive' -Force
```

---

**PowerShell 2**

A solution for PowerShell 2 can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37814462/9447234

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try with the last example which is what I am looking for and gets back o you. Thanks again. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I checked the version and I have Version 4.0. Do you think it will work on 4.0? If not could you please tell me how in Version 4.0.  Thank you

Comment: I tried the code and Expand-archive is not a recognise CMDLET in version 4.0.

Comment: I have given 5 files and 5 folders as an examples but in fact I will be receiving 40 zip files everyday that needs to be extracted in theirs folders. The examples you gave me is working fine in PS5 but I have PS4 version and I cannot upgrade to PS5 because I don't have the permission to do so. Please could you help me out.  Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much Harry. I will try it and Let you know shortly.

Comment: After downloading the module, should I save it in the same folder of the scritp?

Comment: You can save it wherever, you can use the path of the module's manifest, which in this case is the manifest is `Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psd1`.  Saving it in the same folder as the script is likely easiest.

Comment: I notice that I don't have permission to download nor to import anything to prod server. So I am limited to develop the project in PS4. I come up with a solution that works without importing modules: here is the code and it worked. I am suspecious about the performance though.

Comment: $ZipFilesAndFolders = @{
    'FranceData.zip' = 'FranceFolder'
    'USAData.zip' = 'USAFolder'
    'GermanData.zip' = 'GermanFolder'
    'ItalyData.zip' = 'ItalyFolder'
    'DanemarkData.zip' = 'DanemarkFolder'
}
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem") | Out-Null
foreach ($KeyAndValue in $ZipFilesAndFolders.GetEnumerator())
{
    $ZipFilePath = $KeyAndValue.Key
    $DestinationPath = $KeyAndValue.Value
 [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($ZipFilePath, $DestinationPath)
}

Comment: Thank you very much Harry for your help on this. One last thing I would like to ask. Knowing that I will be receiving zip files everyday, I want to overwrite the existing extract files with the new extract files. I do not want to remove the files but just overwrite using the same code that I posted it earlier on.  Thank you